# Detect when workbook is activated / deactivated - OfficeJS Add-in

Tags: excel, office-js

Can an OfficeJS add-in detect whether or not an Excel workbook has been activated or deactivated? For example, when a user clicks away from an add-in hosted workbook to go to a different workbook / application (or goes from a different application to the add-in hosted workbook).

Comment: In the ThisWorkbook private code sheet, VBA has WindowActivate, WindowDeactivate, SheetActivate and SheetDeactivate. Surely you can work by pairing up [tag:office-js] with one of those.

Answer (score 0):

This is planned in requirement set 1.8, and the work is in progress. Please visit the OpenSpec for Excel at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec.

Comment: This is now supported. Please visit [WorksheetCollection.onActivated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#onactivated) and [WorksheetCollection.onDeactivated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#ondeactivated) for details.